# How to set 'enable-cost-allocation' on google GKEs using python API

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a python api equivalent to `gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --enable-cost-allocation`?
I'm thinking it can be done using `gke_compute.projects().locations().clusters().update(SOMETHING)` but not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the [desiredCostManagementConfig](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#Cluster.CostManagementConfig) set to true.

You can also verify it using the gcloud command in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cost-allocations#verify)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. However, we are able to query googles billing database to get the necessary information.